# Digits returns "Invalid phone number" for a valid US phone number

Tags: google-fabric

I am currently using digits for a web-application. I have been testing the application using my personal phone number, which works great. However, after asking my friend to try the app, he could not log in and received the error "Invalid phone number".

This error is very ambiguous. I tested entering his phone number using 3 different devices and different browsers, and the error was the same.
There is not much information that I could find about this error.

In addition to testing on my web-app, I asked him to try to sign into:
digits.com/signin, where he was also unable to log in and received the exact same error, "Invalid phone number". (The problem is not my application).

This error is especially strange since we have phone numbers from the same area code.

My Verizon number : +1 210 789 xxxx

Works fine

His T-Mobile number: +1 210 723 xxxx

Returns error

Any information on this would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Mike from Fabric. This usually means that the routing we need to go between the number and carrier is incorrect; this happens from time-to-time and will either self-solve or you can email support(at)fabric(dot)io with your number and we will group it with other numbers from the same carrier as a way to triage particularly problematic carriers.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I'm having the same problem with one of my users. His number is valid as I'm able to send him text messages directly. But Fabric says his number is invalid

Comment: I'd recommend following up over email as well. Since the number would be needed to look into this further.